# Log variable not working in a SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, row

normally, this is my variable to show the username of the log (related to column *username*)

```
{$user['username']}
```

and in the same way, this is to show the user id (related to column *uid*)

```
{$user['uid']}
```

---

now, I need to show the records from the table notifications only where uid is the one the login has; and i tried:

```
    $query = ("SELECT * FROM notifications WHERE uid = {$user['uid']}");
        $query = mysql_query($query);

<div class="comment_actual_text">
  <span>From: <?php echo $row->uid ?></span><?php echo $row->comments ?>
   <br>
  <span><?php echo $row->time ?</span>
</div>
```

why isn't this working?

Comment: Get rid of the brackets ()...

Comment: Better still, learn to use parametrized queries to keep you safe from SQL injection.

Comment: the issue is with `WHERE uid = {$user['uid']}`
what do you suggest me to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd rather use

```
$user['username'] = "";
```

than

```
{$user['username']} = "";
```

This might also help.

Edit::

```
$sql = ("SELECT * FROM notifications WHERE uid = {$user['uid']}");
        $query = mysql_query($sql);
        $result = mysql_result($query);
```

Try this.

Comment: The brackets can help disambiguate variables encapsulated in quotes, so it may be best to leave them.

Comment: the issue is with `WHERE uid = {$user['uid']}`
what do you suggest me to do?

Comment: Cause as far as I know is mysql_result($query) that returs the array of result.